# Persistent cookie not acting very persistent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-membership

I have implemented a custom membership provider and now I wish to provide my users with the option to let the website remember them, so they do not have to log in every single time they visit.

I've set my cookie to persistent, but it is not acting very persistent. When I close the browser and open it again after logging in the website requires that I log in again.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1,
                model.UserName,
                DateTime.Now,
                (model.RememberMe == true ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(7) : DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60)),
                model.RememberMe,
                userData);
            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

model.RememberMe is in this case a boolean with the value of true, proven by the Visual Studio debugger.

Am I doing something blatantly wrong here?

Comment: You are setting the expiration on the ticket and not the cookie too, you should do both to ensure that the cookie doesn't expire and that the ticket is still considered valid

Comment: @Slicksim Thank you very much! I shall get right to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turned out that I had to specify the expiration for the cookie aswell, as pointed out by Slicksim's comment from Feb 7 '13.